# How to add form data to a table in the same page without having PHP or database?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a modal form. I've been trying to figure out that If I enter data to the form and click submit, It'll automatically display to a table on the same page. Been trying to use JQuery but it won't display.

Answer (score 0):

i hope that is what you are looking for, try it :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>kkgk</title>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
<style>
    table {
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    td,th {
        border:1px solid black;
    }
</style> 
</head> 

<body>

<form class="formulaire">
  <input type="text" class="field1">
  <input type="text" class="field2">
  <input type="submit" value="press">

</form>

<table>
   <tr>
     <th>Nom</th>
     <th>Prenom</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>Clegane</td>
     <td>Hound</td>
   </tr>
</table>

<script>
   $(document).ready(function () {

    $(".formulaire").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        var name = $(".field1").val()
        var pronoun = $(".field2").val()

        $("table").append("<tr><td>"+name+"</td><td>"+pronoun+"</td></tr>")

    })
    })
 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```